# What should I do when my debug output lasts second?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I debug my code at the visual studio it lasts only second, and then disappear so I can't see a solution of the program. What should I do?

Comment: Try putting a break point at the first line and stepping through it.

Comment: use breakpoints (press F9) to pause execution

Comment: I'd recommend you learn to use the visual studio debugger. It's a slight learning curve, sure, but the debugging becomes *much* more effective than printing.